# How can I configure hideshow to hide comments in longer programs only?

Tags: hideshow

If I start Emacs 25 with an init file (`.emacs`) containing

```
(package-initialize)
(load-library "hideshow")
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda () (hs-minor-mode 1)) )
(setq hs-minor-mode-hook  'hs-hide-initial-comment-block)
```

then the initial comments in every Python program I load or view are hidden. I can easily unhide them with `hs-toggle-hiding` (C-c @ C-c). Yet hiding the comments do not help, but rather get in the way, when the file is brief enough to be displayed in its entirety.

How do I configure `hideshow` to hide the initial comment block only if the file loaded is longer than a specific number of lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping the call to `hs-minor-mode` in a check if the buffer has enough likes for it to make sense should suffice, for instance:

```
(lambda ()
  (when (> (count-lines (point-min) (point-max)) 25)
    (hs-minor-mode 1)))
```

Comment: It's likely that this is what the OP wants but be aware that this measures not the buffer size but the size of the current buffer *restriction* (narrowing). If the buffer size is really wanted then use **`0`** instead of `point-min` and **`buffer-size`** instead of `point-max`.

Comment: I don't think OP wanted to keep short files from using `hs-minor-mode` all together, but rather just to skip the `hs-hide-initial-comment-block` step. So something like what you wrote, but for the `hs-minor-mode-hook` instead.

Comment: @Drew What is the current buffer's restriction? Is it the number of CR/CRLF in the file after the hiding? I meant the number of CR/CRLF in the file as it is on disk, before hiding.

Comment: @Omar Right. This would also be nice because (I suspect) it would make it brief to do this setup simultaneously for an arbitrary number of language hooks.

Comment: @Drew I don't think it's likely that the buffer will be narrowed when opened.